# Using flash message instead of @game.errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, ruby-on-rails-4

Instead of using the following (which i think was generated by rails):

```
def create
  @game = current_user.games.create(params[:game])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @game.save
      format.html { redirect_to @game, notice: 'Game was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @game, status: :created, location: @game }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @game.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I want to put the errors into a flash message.  My application.html.erb already has:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
        <%= msg.html_safe %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So it is already able to handle it, but I can't figure out what to do in the controller.  I have no idea how or what populates `@game.errors` but do know that when a model validation fails, it contains why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for rails 2.3.8 but I found it useful anyhow.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html

Flash is just a hash. You can add to it like this:

[Rails - Getting an error message from the model that is not a Validation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695245/rails-getting-an-error-message-from-the-model-that-is-not-a-validation-error)

Sorry for the lazy answer, but it's late and I'm on a tablet. Hope it at least points you in the right direction.